# Python Tensorflow stopped working; cannot import tensorflow due to keras import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I was playing around with a custom object detector through the Tensorflow object detection API in Python. All of a sudden my code stopped working and is producing the following error when trying to import tensorflow:

`from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer ImportError: cannot import name 'Layer' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer'`

I have tried redownloading tensorflow and keras with different versions. I am using python 3.7 and tensorflow 1.15. The keras version I was always using is 2.11.0

Comment: do not use tensorflow.python.keras imports, use directly tensorflow.keras, and import Layer directly from tensorflow.python.keras.layers, not from some internal import that does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for errors such as this. Try to reinstall the packages in a new [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).
In any case, I recommend using the official tensorflow nvidia docker image, it just works.
https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

There is a version mismatch issue. `TensorFlow 1.15` does not support `Keras 2.11`. You need the same version of `TensorFlow` and `Keras`. Please reinstall `TensorFlow` with the latest stable version in your system using the below code:

```
!pip install tensorflow==3.10
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

As `Keras` uses tensorflow as backend, `Keras` will get automatically installed with the same version of `TensorFlow` while installing `TensorFlow`.

To check the installed `Keras` version:

```
import keras
keras.__version__
```